# Position tikzpicture based on coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I need to place a figure made in TikZ in a specific spot of a code listing, where there are only whitespace characters. I have the following document:

[image]

The code which produces is as follows:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1.0,0.4,0}
\lstset{
    % some listing settings
}

\begin{document}

\section{Classic diamond problem}

\lstinputlisting[caption={Classic diamond problem}]{classic-diamond/src}

\input{classic-diamond/fig}

\lstinputlisting{classic-diamond/out}

\end{document}
```

where `classic-diamond/src` and `classic-diamond/out` contain text already visible in the output, while `classic-diamond/fig.tex` has the following contents:

```tex
\begin{figure}[H]\label{figure:e4c}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm]
  \tikzset{     
    e4c node/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=0.8cm,inner sep=0,font=\LARGE}, 
    e4c edge/.style={sloped,above,font=\footnotesize,-{Latex[length=3mm, width=3mm]}}
  }
  \node[e4c node] (A) at (0.0, 1.0) {A}; 
  \node[e4c node] (B) at (-0.5, 0.0) {B}; 
  \node[e4c node] (C) at (0.5, 0.0) {C}; 
  \node[e4c node] (D) at (0.0, -1.0) {D}; 

  \path[->,draw,ultra thick]
  (B) edge[e4c edge,densely dashed]  (A)
  (C) edge[e4c edge,densely dashed]  (A)
  (D) edge[e4c edge]  (B)
  (D) edge[e4c edge]  (C)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
% \caption{Optional caption.}
\end{figure}
```

My goal is to place the figure in the top right corner of the listing and I do not know how to achieve this, despite many existing questions surrounding similar topics, like placing images at specified coordinates, but I do not have an image, I have a tikzpicture.

Comment: Tkae a look at `overlay` and `tikzmark`.

Comment: @projetmbc Thanks! I managed to make it work with `overlay`, `right` and `above`.

Comment: Without a caption, figure [H] is unnecessary (pointless).

Answer (score 1):

Using @projetmbc 's comment I managed to change the tikz file to the following:

```tex
\begin{figure}[H]\label{figure:e4c}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, right=10cm, above=10cm]
  \tikzset{     
    e4c node/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=0.8cm,inner sep=0,font=\LARGE}, 
    e4c edge/.style={sloped,above,font=\footnotesize,-{Latex[length=3mm, width=3mm]}}
  }
  \node[e4c node] (A) at (0.0, 1.0) {A}; 
  \node[e4c node] (B) at (-0.5, 0.0) {B}; 
  \node[e4c node] (C) at (0.5, 0.0) {C}; 
  \node[e4c node] (D) at (0.0, -1.0) {D}; 

  \path[->,draw,ultra thick]
  (B) edge[e4c edge,densely dashed]  (A)
  (C) edge[e4c edge,densely dashed]  (A)
  (D) edge[e4c edge]  (B)
  (D) edge[e4c edge]  (C)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-1.3cm}
```

which results in

[image]

This is more or less what I was looking for.
A couple of downsides of this approach which I noticed:

1. The caption does not move with the figure, and
2. There is a bit of blank space left where the figure would appear, hence the `vspace{-1.3cm}` added at the end of the figure file.

One good thing about this approach is that it is super simple to execute.

Comment: You probably don't want the `figure` environment for that TikZ picture because you place it on top of the listing. It would be better if you could at least mark the place inside the listing where you'd like that figure to appear.